# Issue modifying XML element value with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm using the following PowerShell to update the value of an element in some XML which works fine, but when I save the XML it appears to change the formatting.

```
$xmlFileName = "D:\scripts\DbRestoreDIFF.xml"
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $xmlFileName 
$xmlDoc.TMMsg_CreateTaskReq.taskInfo.subTasks.options.restoreOptions.browseOption.timeRange.toTimeValue = $Timestamp
$xmlDoc.Save($xmlFileName)
```

After I save the document there are several elements where the format goes from:

```
<alert>
<alertName></alertName>
</alert>
```

to:

```
<alert>
  <alertName>
   </alertName>
</alert>
```

I've tried preserving whitespace but it didn't seem to help. This is causing me an issue as I'm them unable to pass the XML correctly.

Comment: What do you mean with `_pass the XML correctly_` ? What issues are cause by this?

Comment: It isn't read correctly by the application that reads it, which in this instance is Commvault. It assumes there is a value supplied when it is actually blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values in XmlDocument's `save()` are cause for this issue. As described, start and end tags are on different lines:

```
[xml]$x = '<alert> <alertName></alertName> </alert>'
$x.save([console]::out)
# Output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<alert>
  <alertName>
  </alertName>
</alert>
```

To control the output formatting, use an [XmlWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=netcore-3.1) with [XmlWriterSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings?view=netcore-3.1). An example that saves output to console is like so,

```
[xml]$x = '<alert> <alertName></alertName> </alert>'
$settings = $(new-object Xml.XmlWriterSettings)
$settings.Indent = $true
$settings.IndentChars = "`t"

$xmlWriter = [Xml.XmlWriter]::create([console]::out, $settings)
$x.save($xmlWriter)
$xmlWriter.close()

# Output
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<alert>
        <alertName></alertName>
</alert>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. A variation of the above enabled me to update the XML as expected.